# Writing type predicate function without type assertions

Tags: typescript, predicate, typeguards, narrowing

Now that TypeScript supports both type narrowing via the `in` operator and the `satisfies` keyword, as of [version 4.9](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html), I've been looking for a standardised way to write a [type predicate function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) in a type safe way, without using any type assertions.

That way, if a type definition changes, TypeScript will know that the typeguard function for that type is no longer correct.

However, I'm running into some issues where it looks like TypeScript is correctly figuring out the types of each of an object's properties, but hasn't correctly narrowed the type of the object itself.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```js
type MyType = {
    foo: string;
};

function isMyType(data: unknown): data is MyType {
    if (!(
        typeof data === 'object' &&
        data !== null
    )) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!(
        'foo' in data &&
        typeof data.foo === 'string'
    )) {
        return false;
    }

    data.foo; // <- Typed correctly as `string`
    data; // <- Typed incorrectly as `object & Record<"foo", unknown>`

    /* Error: 
    Type 'object & Record<"foo", unknown>' does not satisfy the expected type 'MyType'.
        Types of property 'foo' are incompatible.
            Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'. */
    data satisfies MyType;

    return true;
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQBIAZgezwC4oBnYAJwEsA7AcwG4MBfRjHAV2oGNhK9qolEnESQAFABMAhsCnFOAa2p4A7tQCUxabMElYCJOmyUcUMQEIx2LKEh5T2qVGQuoAcjwAjAFYQebqAAyQOtHKHNXanYAG2jsdXUjLCxyCGB2cgEcKWiSCEYsJgxjUwsrZLd8PACaKDDg61sIezqZKQA6KudXNzIqOjd4xMxk1PTMqGzc-Owi7EdOgnooAHoVqAAeAFooUQgJKC48clSeaJAoKT0AAz6aWmv5tuW1zZ29g5ojk79gc8ubl5fDwglAAEp+Y4SDYAIiqMIANFBFMo1AA+R7YFYAKigAFETsdiNg9u4gb9QRDvtC4QREcjqEpVNQ0QEJHgIHplMBSDIhDgLsAABbQCAAD0gPH2UCa7hESDc7Wsez0LTA5DwkHIoHcVQCUlSgm4eAAtmA+Z5ohAlcksKS3CjmTUuXgeVcSJRaNQpJboMA8DLDL0KPdFVBsSsnjoSHySDhKJz9HtWCk0hkBBR2DMmEA)

As I've commented in that example, after narrowing the type of `data` using the `in` operator, TypeScript understands that it has a `foo` property.

However, despite the type of its `foo` property having been narrowed to `string` using the `typeof` operator, the object's overall type is still `object & Record<"foo", unknown>` rather than `object & Record<"foo", string>`.

What I'm finding particularly confusing, though, is if I go and access `data.foo` then TypeScript understands perfectly well that its type is `string`.

The only solution to this that I've been able to think of so far is to create an additional type predicate function to tell TypeScript how to narrow the type of properties of `data`, like this:

```js
type MyType = {
    foo: string;
};

function isMyType(data: unknown): data is MyType {
    if (!(
        typeof data === 'object' &&
        data !== null
    )) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!(
        'foo' in data &&
        propertyIsType(data, 'foo', isString)
    )) {
        return false;
    }

    data.foo; // <- Typed correctly as `string`
    data; // <- Typed as `object & Record<"foo", unknown>` & Record<"foo", string>

    // No error
    data satisfies MyType;

    return true;
}

/**
 * Narrow the type of an object based on a test on a particular property's type
 */
function propertyIsType<
    R, PropName extends string | number | symbol, T
>(
    data: R & Record<PropName, unknown>,
    propName: PropName,
    predicate: (prop: unknown) => prop is T
): data is R & Record<PropName, T> {
    return predicate(data[propName]);
}

/**
 * Utility type predicate for the `string` type
 */
function isString(data: unknown): data is string { return typeof data === 'string'; }
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQBIAZgezwC4oBnYAJwEsA7AcwG4MBfRjHAV2oGNhK9qolEnESQAFABMAhsCnFOAa2p4A7tQCUxabMElYCJOmyUcUMQEIx2LKEh5T2qVGQuoAcjwAjAFYQebqAAyQOtHKHNXanYAG2jsdXUjLCxyCGB2cgEcKWiSCEYsJgxjUwsrZLd8PACaKDDg6zByPEhyUABJElEISRkpABp3KrdBoQBlChpadXjEzGTU9MyobNz87CLsRwA6KvooAHoDqAAeAFoobokoLjxyVJ5okCgpPQADMio6N62+-aPThcri93l5fDwglAAEp+O4SE4AIiqCMGimUagAfG9ITDbuR4UiCCjSJM6BjilgAQA5PBQCD3O6-HQkGRCHCUCB6ERIVgpNIZAQUdjrTYHABUYowUDFUCpUgZKigwAAFtBbNB7C8BGC-MAoJ5XhBrvwXkrOXqTU4wPLeFwYvKoE0WvTQG49OqpWKDmxODw+AIna0Ol0kCdsFDBgAFZpgOUAW2gEAAHsAINQJHpPlMoAAfKBROOeem50ggQt4aKDeAYDHlRzEKE42H4k7RlrxiCo6hKVTUDH9bCBjvENuxqQJgdYJpGyhcGQQYhiQPybvojTODGOmO6S4YTR1Po7xuBaHN+GjjtVzfzRYCrczuep3qyADaQ-HEAAuupGKKJZ6oAAVV4aJKFAJVDGnCRZ3nFY7iVVUoA+UlaGxD1pW9DhuF4E1xhQ585CgNFe33MIhBJL5aHQKBb2WdVNTCFxUDdFC3H2IogA)

But this solution doesn't feel great to me because of how it requires both a utility `propertyIsType` function and utility type predicate functions like `isString` for each type that needs to be tested, even primitive types.

It also feels a little messy that my implementation of `propertyIsType` doesn't replace the `Record<"foo", unknown>` part of the type, instead only adding `Record<"foo", string>`, but at least that's not causing any issues.

Is there a better solution to narrowing types like `Record<"foo", unknown>` to `Record<"foo", string>`?

Comment: I see `(parameter) data: object & Record<"foo", unknown> & Record<"foo", string>
`

Comment: A better approach is probably to automatically generate your type predicates from the type declarations themselves. There are projects like [ts-auto-guard](https://github.com/rhys-vdw/ts-auto-guard) which do this for you, and you can just run it as part of your build process. Then the type predicate functions will always match the type definition after a build. (Disclaimer: I haven't used or tested ts-auto-guard, that's just the first one I found by searching.)

Comment: @kaya3 I have my own tool for automatically generating type predicate functions, which I'm looking to improve by changing to an approach like this. So using another tool isn't really a great option for me, but I appreciate the link nonetheless

Comment: It is a known and outstanding issue in TS that narrowing a property of an object does not affect the type of the object. I'll dig up the link sometime, if someone else doesn't before me.

Comment: The common solution is to check the type of the property in a typeguard, along the lines of `propIsString<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, prop: K): T is T & Record<K, string>`.

Comment: Thanks @DarrylNoakes, I guess what I had in mind is not currently possible then, oh well. I'm pretty sure I've found the issue you're thinking of, about this being a known issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384

Comment: I see now that you did actually mention the solution I gave in your second example. My bad. Nice generic method, tho; I'm gonna save that :)

Answer (score -1):

You may simplify your check into

```
type MyType = {
    foo: string;
};

interface typeofMap {
    'number': number
    'string': string
}

function propIs<K extends string, T extends keyof typeofMap>(
    o: unknown, k: K, t: T
): o is { [P in K]: typeofMap[T] } {
    return typeof o === 'object' && o !== null && k in o && typeof (o as Record<K, any>)[k] === t
}

function isMyType(data: unknown): data is MyType {
    if (!propIs(data, 'foo', 'string')) {
        return false;
    }

    data.foo; // <- Typed correctly as `string`
    data; // <- Typed as `(parameter) data: { foo: string; }

    // No error
    data satisfies MyType;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: That `typeofMap` solution only works if every property is of a primitive type that can be checked with `typeof`. But to support more complex property types, such as arrays or objects, I will need to be able to pass a type predicate function to do those more complex checks.