# how to make typescript happy when checking for optional values?

Tags: typescript

I have this code:

```
{user?.email != null && user?.id != null && user?.name != null && (
        <Dashboard
          user={{
            ...user,
            imageURL: session.user.image!,
          }}
          pages={pages}
        />
      )}
```

But the value of the spread user still is showing a TS error

```
Type '{ imageURL: string; id: string; name: string | null; email: string | null; }' is not assignable to type '{ id: string; name: string; email: string; imageURL: string; }'.
  Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

why is a value like `name` still picked up by typescript as being `string | null` when the checking logic `user?.name != null` should make it such that the value user.name is a non-optional value? How do I fix this?

Comment: You aren't checking if user is defined - if user is undefined, then user?.name is not null, but undefined. So add `user &&` to beginning of condition or check explicitly also for undefined with `user?.name !== null && user?.name !== undefined`.

Comment: @MatijaSirk If `user?.name != null` is `true`, that already implies user is defined. Because `undefined == null` is `true`. If something is `!= null`, it cannot be undefined.

Comment: @RickyMo I learned something new today, thanks. I am too used to === behaviour and jumped to comment button too quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76177676/writing-type-predicate-function-without-type-assertions) about a month ago and got a good answer in the comments. TypeScript does things a little strangely when narrowing property types, such as with the `in` operator. It will narrow the type of the property just as you'd expect but treats the type of the parent differently. Here's [the relevant issue on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384)

This is a limitation of TypeScript itself, but it is possible to work around it by defining your own typeguard function to tell TypeScript how you intend for it to narrow a type.

For example:

```
type User = {
  email: string | null;
  id: string | null;
  name: string | null;
};

/** The same as `User`, but the properties aren't nullable */
type CompleteUser = Record<keyof User, NonNullable<User[keyof User]>>;

function isCompleteUser(user: User): user is CompleteUser {
  return user?.email != null && user?.id != null && user?.name != null;
}

// ...

{isCompleteUser(user) && (
  // TypeScript now knows that properties like `user.email` aren't null, and also understands how to narrow the type of `user`
}
```

Of course, if you need a very generic approach then this can take a bit more work or complexity, but hopefully that suggestion is useful for your specific use case.

Comment: thanks. I'm confused because I feel like the same kind of refinement seems to happen here, but this works:
```
function foo(x: number | null): string {
  if (x != null) {
    return bar(x);
  }
  return "default string";
}

function bar(y: number) {
  return "hi";
}
```

Comment: @reactor narrowing a type directly, like narrowing the type of the `x` argument in that example, works as you'd expect. It's only unexpected when you narrow the type of an object's property. Here's [an example in the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUAPAXIg3ogBwCc4CcwQBbAIwFMjEAfRCgG1cQF8BKHAZyhEYYAOZ4AUIimIYwRJgB0xUogCEAXhYh23CdP2IitKCCJJqAQyKZuAbknTODqc8PHTSAEQATWsAvaUIgCQqKe9k7ioJCwCIiW1gCeOPjKZFo09Fy6uK5GJmaIngAWMOHinEA) of how that wouldn't work as you might expect if you try to narrow an object's type based on its property, instead.